# Open Street Map map export

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis, geotiff, pyqgis

How to export country map, not only lines, polygons and points, but with roads, streets, etc. Tried to download this one http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/ukraine.html, but it consists only of points, lines, multipolygons.

Comment: The pbf and osm.bz2 formats from Geofabrik contain everything. Not quite sure about the Shapefiles but I'm pretty sure they will also contain almost everything. Are you really sure that there is something missing? Note that OSM consists only of [three basic elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements): nodes, ways and relations.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.